# How to compare two massive spark dataframes on row level and print the difference

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two very large spark dataframes. I want to compare it on row level and print only the differences

eg:

`df1= firstname:abc lastname:xyz company:123`

---

`df2= firstname:abc lastname:xyz company:456`

---

expected output-`diff= company(df1):123 company(df2):456`

Comment: What is the expected output? 
Please show us what you've tried

Comment: Expected output should only show me the row difference. i tried this :https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/api/sparkcompare.html but the output is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

As of me,there is no optimal solution for the problem you have described. Because, a difference between dataframes can be found only when you have a `column/reference` on which both the dataframes could be joined.

With that note, one approach will be to use `subtract` function find the difference which helps to some extent.

```
>>> df_1.show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|fname|lname|cmpny|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  abc|  xyz|  123|
+-----+-----+-----+

>>> df_2.show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|fname|lname|cmpny|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  abc|  xyz|  456|
+-----+-----+-----+

>>> df_1.select('*').subtract(df_2.select('*')).show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|fname|lname|cmpny|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  abc|  xyz|  123|
+-----+-----+-----+

>>> df_2.select('*').subtract(df_1.select('*')).show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|fname|lname|cmpny|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  abc|  xyz|  456|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#except(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset))

`df1.except(df2)`

will return rows in df1 not in df2.